# Unable to use the UI on a WD MyCloud

Tags: nas

When I try to access the admin interface for my Western Digital "My Cloud" NAS, the page is stuck on

> "Reading configuration information..."

Looking a the console, I can see two 500 errors:

[image]

I'm unsure as to when the issue first appeared, I found out when trying to access it to reactivate SSH access.

It used to work fine, I may have broken something via SSH (I did an apt-get update and install).

Comment: Why are people voting to close this question? If you have a suggestion, leave a comment.

Comment: Found others with the same problem https://community.wd.com/t/factory-reset-without-dashboard/94519/5